# Consecutivo C# alfanumérico

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

Quiero generar un valor único en C# por ejemplo  `AA-00-01`, `AA-00-02` hasta llegar al `80` y de ahí que siga con `AA-01-80`, `AA-02-80` , hasta completar al `80` igualmente, PERO cuando llega a `AA-80-80` ocupo que ahora continúe con `AB`....`AZ` , y luego con todas sus posibles combinaciones (`BA`,`BC`, `CA` , etc)

Alguna idea de cómo arrancar?

Ejemplos

> AA-80-80
>
> AB-80-80
>
> AZ-80-80
>
> BA-01-80
>
> BA-02-80

Saludos developers :)

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, lo primero decirte que deberías añadir que has intentado hasta ahora, ya que aquí lo que se pretende es ayudar y no realizar la tarea de nadie. Te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y aquí te dejo un [mcve]

Comment: Una pregunta, Estas utilizando una base de datos para almacenar información, te pregunto eso, debido que te puedo dar una solución con concepto de base de datos, saludos

Answer (score 1):

Lo que debes hacer es generar una lista con todas las posibles combinaciones, al tener tu lista solo debes enviar el número que deseas convertir a un identificador alfanumérico con lo que identificaras mediante ese número al `string` de la lista.

Lo que hice fue generar un arreglo con el alfabeto y una lista con los números desde el 0 hasta el 80.

Luego de eso, cree 4 ciclos `foreach` donde 2 son para obtener las combinaciones de letras en pares y los otros 2 son para obtener el primer y el segundo número hasta el 80.

De ahí ir incrementando cada vez que se llegue al límite de la lista o el arreglo según corresponda.

```
private string obtenerAlfanumerico(int Id)
{
    //DECLARACIÓN DE VARIABLES
    char[] alfabeto = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();
    List<int> numeros = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, 81));
    List<string> listaIdentificadores = new List<string>();
    //GENERAR LISTA DE COMBINACIONES DE ALFANUMÉRICOS
    foreach (char letraI in alfabeto)
        foreach (char letraJ in alfabeto)
            foreach (int numeroI in numeros)
                foreach (int numeroJ in numeros)
                    listaIdentificadores.Add(
                        letraI.ToString() +
                        letraJ.ToString() +
                        " - " + numeroI.ToString("D2") +
                        " - " + numeroJ.ToString("D2")
                        );
    //RETORNAR EL IDENTIFICADOR SOLICITADO
    return listaIdentificadores.Skip(Id).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para lo que requieres tienes que hacer un split('-') e implementar la lógica de incremento para cada sección, esta seria mi solucion, utilizando recursividad para imprimir todos los siguientes valores hasta llegar a ZZ-80-80

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = "AA-00-00";
        printOutPut(input);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void printOutPut(string input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(input);
        if (input == "ZZ-80-80")
            return;

        var elements = input.Split('-');
        var element2 = elements[2];
        var element1 = elements[1];
        elements[2] = element2 == "80" ? elements[2] : NextNumber2D(elements[2]);
        elements[1] = element2 == "80" && element1 != "80" ? NextNumber2D(elements[1]) : elements[1];
        elements[0] = element2 == "80" && element1 == "80" ? NextAlphabet2D(elements[0]) : elements[0];

        printOutPut($"{elements[0]}-{elements[1]}-{elements[2]}");
    }

    private static string NextNumber2D(string value)
    {
        var number = Convert.ToInt32(value);
        return (++number).ToString("D2");
    }

    private static string NextAlphabet2D(string value)
    {
        var letters = value.ToCharArray();
        letters[1] = NextChar(letters[1]);
        letters[0] = letters[1] == 'A' ? NextChar(letters[0]) : letters[0];
        return new string(letters);
    }

    private static char NextChar(char letter)
    {
        return letter == 'Z' ? 'A' : (char)(letter + 1);
    }
}
```

output:

```
AA-00-00
AA-00-01
AA-00-02
AA-00-03
AA-00-04
AA-00-05
AA-00-06
.
.
.
ZT-80-80
ZU-80-80
ZV-80-80
ZW-80-80
ZX-80-80
ZY-80-80
ZZ-80-80
```

Espero te sirva, Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Primero, no ha quedado claro cual es el paso después de `AA-00-80`, si `AA-01-00` o `AA-01-80`. Tampoco está claro cual es el paso después de `AZ-80-80`, si `BA-80-80` o `BA-00-00` o ...

Te digo cómo lo haría yo de una manera 'manual', y usando todas las combinaciones posibles:

Crea un primer valor `myString = "AA-00-00"`

Dentro de un bucle, parseas ese `string` introduciendo cada pareja de caracteres en una variable

```
var1 = myString.Split("-")(0); 
var2 = myString.Split("-")(1); 
var3 = ...
```

convirtiendo a su vez `var2` y `var3` en `Integers`.

Deberías también separar `var1` en sus dos caracteres (`var1decena` y `var1unidad`) para más tarde hacer el incremento fácilmente.

En cada iteración del bucle, incrementas `var3`. Si ha llegado a `81`, lo cambias a `00` e incrementas `var2`. Si `var2` ha llegado a `81`, lo cambias a `00` e incrementas `var1unidad`. Si `var1unidad` es `Z`, lo cambias a `A` e incrementas `var1decena`.

Cuando llegues a `ZZ-80-80` deberías parar la iteración o resetearlo a `AA-00-00` o lo que decidas.

Comment: +1 a la edición, gracias! se ve mucho más claro todo, para la próxima lo haré por mí mismo

Comment: De nada :) Si, siempre es mejor tratar de que nuestras publicaciones sean lo mas legibles posibles. Si necesitas ayuda con los formatos, no dudes en preguntar

Comment: No creo que deba hacerse con splits, lo correcto es que se manejen como campos separados y que haya un campo computado en la BD que ya concatene todos

Comment: No ha dicho nada de BD, no sería contraproducente? Pregunto eh, entre acceder a la base de datos y eso... no debería hacerse en código?

Answer (score -1):

Prueba esto creo que te ayudará.

```
for (int valor = 65; valor < 91; valor++)
{
     char letra = (char)(valor);
     Console.WriteLine(letra);
}

Console.Read();
```

Answer (score -1):

Bien, obviamente hay cientos de formas de solucionar este problema. A pesar de que deberías habernos mostrado que habías intentado para solucionarlo por tu cuenta, considero que esta pregunta puede ser útil a mucha mas gente, y de ahí que la responda. Te voy a presentar una manera de solucionarlo.

La idea se basa en crear dos listas, una con todas las combinaciones de las letras, y otra con todos los números del `0` al `80`. Una vez tenemos estas listas, no hay mas que tener 3 bucles `for` anidados que vayan recorriendo las listas obteniendo los elementos en el orden adecuado.

El código sería el siguiente. Hago uso de [`yield`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) de tal manera que los elementos se obtienen de uno en uno de forma diferida:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> ObtenerValor()
{
    var letras = Enumerable.Range('A', 'Z' - 'A' + 1).Select(c => (char)c).ToArray();

    var combinaciones = new List<string>();
    //creamos las combinaciones de letras
    for (int i = 0; i < letras.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < letras.Length; j++)
        {
            combinaciones.Add(letras[i].ToString() + letras[j].ToString());
        }
    }

    //creamos el enumerable con los numeros
    var numeros = Enumerable.Range(0, 81).ToList();

    //Ahora creamos el IEnumerable con todos los valores
    for (int i=0; i < letras.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<numeros.Count;j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < numeros.Count; k++)
            {
                string valor = combinaciones[i] + "-" + numeros[j].ToString("00") + "-" + numeros[k].ToString("00");
                yield return valor;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

La forma de usarlo es la siguiente, por ejemplo:

```
//Este bucle imprime todas las combinaciones
foreach (var valor in ObtenerValor())
{
    Console.WriteLine(valor);
}
```

O,si quieres ir a un elemento en concreto, puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
Console.WriteLine(ObtenerValor().Skip(81).First()); //devuelve AA-01-00
```